# Conic Sections and Complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

If $\omega$ is a complex number such that $\omega$ describes the set of complex numbers such that $|\omega|=q \ne 1$, then the complex number $$z = \omega + \frac{1}{\omega}$$
describes a conic. The distance between the foci of the conic described by $z$ is?

I attempted to rewrite this in cartesian form but to no avail.
How do i proceed?

Comment: Try the polar form.

Comment: $|\omega|\ne 1$ or $|\omega|=1$?

Comment: It doesn't equal 1.

Comment: The set $\{\omega\in\Bbb C:|\omega|\ne 1\}$ is open, holohorphic functions are open. The image set *can't* be a curve.

Comment: Do you mean that we are to select a constant $a$ such that $a \ne 1$, and then let $\omega$ range over the set of complex numbers such that $|\omega| = a$?

Comment: Yes. In fact, if $a=1$ the "conic" is degenerate.

Comment: I meant to ask @user90709 if $|\omega|$ was meant to be constant but I have decided to proceed on the assumption that it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $q \in \mathbb{R}$, $q \ne 1$, and let $\omega$ range over all $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|\omega| = q$.  Then we can write
$$ \omega = q \cos \theta + iq \sin \theta $$
and
$$ \frac{1}{\omega} = \frac{1}{q} \cos \theta - \frac{i}{q} \sin \theta $$
where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore
$$ z = \omega + \frac{1}{\omega} =
    \left(q + \frac{1}{q}\right) \cos \theta + i\left(q - \frac{1}{q}\right) \sin \theta. $$
That is, 
\begin{equation} z = a \cos \theta + ib \sin \theta,\tag{1}\end{equation}
where
$a = q + \frac{1}{q}$ and $b = q - \frac{1}{q}$.
Equation ($1$) is the equation of an ellipse with semimajor axis $a$ and semiminor axis $|b|$, whose foci are therefore separated by the distance $2 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} = 4$.
Not coincidentally, $4$ is also the length of the line segment generated by 
$z = \omega + \frac{1}{\omega}$ where $|\omega| = 1$.

Comment: This question could be also solved by using [Joukowsky transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform).