# Conic Sections formulae using Complex Numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, soft-question, conic-sections

I have been preparing for the JEE Examination here in India and have been studying Complex Numbers for the past few days. One of the topics which falls under Complex Numbers is their application in Coordinate Geometry (Conic Sections). These include the following:

> Equation of lines in different forms (parametric/non-parametric)$$$$
>     Equations of Circles with various conditions (for example centered at $z_0$, or orthogonal to another circle and so on)$$$$
>     Equations of Ellipses and Hyperbolas and so on.

$$$$
There are several other applications/equations mentioned which I haven't written here. The trouble I'm facing is that the book I use for Complex Numbers (Algebra for JEE Main and Advanced, by SK Goyal) only has the formulae listed without showing the derivations. I find it extremely hard to just accept and use a formula/result without knowing how it came into existence.

$$$$

I would be grateful if somebody could please mention a source/reference book from which I could actually learn how to derive/reach all the formulae used for represinting Conics using Complex Numbers. The book does not necessarily have to match the level of the JEE Advanced Examination; it can be higher than that too. However I would prefer it if the book was at the level suitable for the JEE Advanced level only.

$$$$Many thanks in advance!
$$$$
Edit:$$$$ The results mentioned in my book are as follows:
$$$$

> $1) $The equation of the line joining $z_1$ and $z_2$ is $$z(\bar{z_1}-\bar{z_2})-\bar{z}(z_1-z_2)+ z_1\bar z_2-z_2\bar z_1=0 \text{ (non parametric form).}$$

$$$$

> $2) $Three points are collinear if $$\begin{vmatrix}z_1&\bar{z_1}&1\\z_2&\bar {z_2}& 1\\z_3&\bar {z_3}& 1\end{vmatrix}=0$$

$$$$

> $3)$$\bar{a}z+\bar z a+b=0$ where $b\in \mathbb R$ describes the equation of a straight line (I don't know what $a$ is, nor what $\iota b$ is).

$$$$

> $4)$ The real and complex slope (I don't know what is meant by 'real' and 'complex') of the line $\bar{a}z+\bar z a+b=0$  are $-\dfrac{\Re(a)}{\Im(a)}$ and $-\dfrac{a}{\bar a}$ where $b\in \mathbb R$.

$$$$

> $5) $If the lines $\bar{a}z+\bar z a+k_1=0$ and $\bar{b}z+\bar b a+k_2=0$ $k_1,k_2\in \mathbb R$ are perpendicular to each other, then $$\bar{a}b+\bar ba=0$$

$$$$

> $6)$ $z\bar z +a\bar z +\bar az+k=0 $ where $k\in \mathbb R$ represents a circle with center $-a$ and radius $\sqrt{|a|^2-k}$.

$$$$

> $7)$ If $|z-z_1|+|z-z_2|=2a$ where $2a>|z_1-z_2|$ then $ z $ represents an ellipse with foci at $z_1 \text{ and }z_2$ and $a\in \mathbb R^+ $.

$$$$

> $8)$ If  $|z-z_1|-|z-z_2|=2a$ where $2a<|z_1-z_2|$ then $z$ represents a hyperbola with foci at $z_1$ and $z_2$.

$$$$

> $9)$ Equation of all circles orthogonal to $|z-z_1|=r_1\text{ and }|z-z_2|=r_2$ is (nothing further is mentioned).

$$$$

> $10)$ $\left |\dfrac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right | = k$ is a circle if $k\neq 1$ and will represent a line if $k=1$.

$$$$

> $11)$ The equation $|z-z_1|^2+|z-z_2|^2=k$ will represent a circle if $k\geq \frac12 |z_1-z_2|^2$.

$$$$

> $12)$ If $\arg\left(\dfrac{(z_2-z_3)(z_1-z_4)}{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)}\right)=0, \pm \pi$, then the points $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ are concyclic.

Comment: It might help if you would write out a few of the formulas, so we would know what sort of reference to look for.

Comment: You could also see whether http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481582/equation-of-ellipse-hyperbola-parabola-in-complex-form is any help, or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786215/conic-sections-and-complex-numbers, or https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Math185/Conics.pdf, or anything else you get by typing Conic Sections formulae using Complex Numbers into the internet.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for responding Sir. I've edited my question to include the results mentioned in the book. These were actually mentioned as extra points, but these are frequently used to solved questions in the JEE papers. I would be truly grateful if you could please show me how to derive all these results, or give me a source from which I could learn how to derive them. Once again, many thanks Sir!

Comment: @GerryMyerson PS. Sir I've tried multiple times to format the edit properly, but it just isn't working. I hope you will excuse it Sir.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the links I gave? Were any of them helpful?

Comment: Sir, I looked at all three links. I wasn't able to derive the results (and their conditions) which I have written using the link to the berkley webpage. I could understand the link where the conic section had to be understood. I was also able to understand why the equations $7$ and $8$ would represent an ellipse and hyperbola respectively, but was unable to understand why the focii should be where they are, nor the condition regarding $2a$. Please could you help me out Sir?

Comment: If you are preparing for jee you can join us here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48921/discussions-in-pcm-and-anything-else @Ishan

Comment: I recommend **Zwikker, C.** (1968). *The Advanced Geometry of Plane Curves and Their Applications*, Dover Press. This can be found in a pdf file online.

Comment: Very surprised a standard book like SK Goyal doesn't have any derivations. Have you checked Cengage? You can also check in the series by Sanjay Mishra. Anyways, most of them are fairly straightforward, I would say think about them first on your own. You can also always watch Unacademy/Mohit Tyagi sir's lectures on YouTube, I think they have covered most if not all derivations.

Answer (score 1):

There's detail discussion for general conics in Masayo Fujimuraa's paper:

[*The Complex Geometry of Blaschke Products of Degree 3 and Associated Ellipses*](https://www.pmf.ni.ac.rs/filomat-content/2017/31-1/31-1-8-3729.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

1)Follows from 3.  In 3) $a$ represents a direction (actually normal to a direction), and $b$ represents a distance from the origin -- or $\left |\frac {b}{a}\right|$ does.

2)In cartesian:

$\left|\begin {array} {} x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\\x_3&y_3&1\end{array}\right| = 0$ suggests $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), (x_3,y_3)$ are colinear

-- or the pyramid formed by the 3 points in the plane $z = 1$ together with the origin forms a pyramid of zero volume.

$\begin {bmatrix} {} z_1&\bar z_1&1\\z_2&\bar z_2&1\\z_3&\bar z_3&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin {bmatrix} x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\\x_3&y_3&1\end{bmatrix}\begin {bmatrix} 1&1&0\\i&-i&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

The right most matrix is non-sigular.

6)$\overline{(z-z_1)}(z-z_2) = k$  is the locus of points $z$ such that $\angle z_1zz_2$ is constant.

7)is the very definition of an ellipse.  The distance from one focus to a point on the ellipse to the other focus is constant.

10)$|z - z_1| = k|z-z_2|\\
(z - z_1)\overline (z-z_1) = k^2 (z - z_2)\overline (z-z_2)\\
x^2 + y^2 + 2xx_1 + 2yy_1 + x_1^2 + y_1^2 = k^2(x^2 + y^2 + 2xx_2 + 2yy_2 + x_2^2 + y_2^2)\\ 
(k^2 - 1)(x^2 - a)^2 + (k^2 - 1)(y^2 - b)^2  = r^2$