# Conic in a complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, conic-sections

This question may have been asked before..

what is the complex form through five points of a conic section in the complex plane?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: The real point matrix is known but not mentioned as it may not be of direct use here. With any hint I would try improving my down voted question.

Answer (score 0):

In complex plane, we use $z$ and $\bar z$ as bases.  Hence,

$$0=F(z,\bar z) \equiv \det
\begin{pmatrix}
  (z+\bar z)^2 & z^2-\bar z^2 & (z-\bar z)^2
  & z & \bar z & 1 \\
  (z_1+\bar z_1)^2 & z_1^2-\bar z_1^2 & (z_1-\bar z_1)^2 &
  z_1 & \bar z_1 & 1 \\
  (z_2+\bar z_2)^2 & z_2^2-\bar z_2^2 & (z_2-\bar z_2)^2 &
  z_2 & \bar z_2 & 1 \\
  (z_3+\bar z_3)^2 & z_3^2-\bar z_3^2 & (z_3-\bar z_3)^2 &
  z_3 & \bar z_3 & 1 \\
  (z_4+\bar z_4)^2 & z_4^2-\bar z_4^2 & (z_4-\bar z_4)^2 &
  z_4 & \bar z_4 & 1 \\
  (z_5+\bar z_5)^2 & z_5^2-\bar z_5^2 & (z_5-\bar z_5)^2 &
  z_5 & \bar z_5 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and may further rearrange into

$$\bar u z^2+pz\bar z+u\bar z^2+\bar v z+v\bar z+q=0$$

with $p,q\in \mathbb{R}$.

Please see also my older posts in [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628698/general-formula-for-equidistant-locus-of-three-points/1628779#1628779) and [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1957928/conic-sections-formulae-using-complex-numbers/4073189#4073189).

Comment: This is mostly wrong, since the source-pdf in the link needs the coefficients of $z^2$ and $\bar{z}^2$ to be conjugate as well as those of $z$ and $\bar{z},$ and the coefficients of $z\bar{z}$ and $1$ to be real. In fact, it's a real equation with imaginary part $0$, dressed up as a complex equation. Your "equation" in most cases becomes two; one from the real part and one from the imaginary part. You'd be better off doing the determinant calculation as usual in ${\Bbb R}^2$ and retrofitting to $\bar{u}z^2+pz\bar{z}+u\bar{z}^2+\bar{v}z+v\bar{z}+q=0, p,q\in {\Bbb R}.$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland, You're right and I've jumped to conclusion carelessly.  I've revised my answer finally.